# How disable run at startup feature in android studio?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

My application works fine but i started noticing that whenever I don't have the app open an error message dubbed "UNFORTUNATELY, (your app) has stopped working". I tried to rewrite the code to dump the cached files overtime the user exits the app but the error kept showing up.. I now realise that it has something to do with the background activity. When i went into settings/application manager/my app i realised it has "run at startup" enabled for it. I really need to know how to turn this feature off because I searched everywhere and found nothing (anything needs to be changed in my .XML file?).. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review your AndroidManifest.xml file again and remove unnecessary permissions.

Comment: i checked, do you suppose the "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" permission could be the culprit ?

Comment: maybe you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`. try removing other permissions and test.

Comment: @Rayyan include AndroidManifest.xml and reboot your mobile while plugging it in pc with Android Studio running. This might reveal the problem in logical and let you see the crash point. Also try after removing `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Answer (score 0):

Find in Manifest string like this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: so i'd want to remove that permission from my manifest ? what about the "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" ?

Comment: I think only BOOT_COMPLETED need del